# Error in matlab2tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, matlab2tikz

I am attempting to plot two graphs together in one plot using matlab2tikz and I am facing a basic syntax issue that I have been trying hours to search for.

The error is as follow:
`Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.`  I have referenced the line overleaf saying its causing the error in the code below.

I have rewrote the code below but with exculding the I/O data vector because they are too large to be fitted in this tex-exchange website.

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
%
%The latest updates can be retrieved from
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz
%where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.448in,
height=3.461in,
at={(0.831in,0.481in)},
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={white!40!black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{white!40!black}},
every x tick/.append style={white!40!black},
xmin=1,
xmax=411,
every outer y axis line/.append style={white!40!black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{white!40!black}},
every y tick/.append style={white!40!black},
ymin=-1,
ymax=0.8,
ylabel style={font=\color{white!40!black}},
ylabel={y1},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
]
\addplot [color=white!60!black, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   0.2845\\
2   0.2365\\
3   0.0805\\
4   -0.0615\\
5   -0.0115\\
6   -0.1195\\
7   -0.1795\\
8   -0.1185\\
9   -0.2065\\
10  -0.1515\\
11  -0.0105\\
12  0.0485\\
13  0.2055\\
14  0.2975\\
15  0.3405\\
16  0.4775\\
17  0.5205\\
18  0.5275\\
19  0.6015\\
20  0.6165\\
};
\addlegendentry{m1: 88.97\%}
\end{axis}%%%%%%%%%%%%OVERLEAF IS POINTING TOWARDS THIS LINE AS SOURCE OF ERROR

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.521in,
height=3.566in,
at={(0.758in,0.481in)},
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={white!40!black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{white!40!black}},
every x tick/.append style={white!40!black},
xmin=1,
xmax=411,
every outer y axis line/.append style={white!40!black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{white!40!black}},
every y tick/.append style={white!40!black},
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
axis line style={draw=none},
ticks=none
]
\addplot [color=white!60!black, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{
1   0.284500056219376\\
2   0.23650004412451\\
3   0.0805000155159026\\
4   -0.0615000481945472\\
5   -0.0115000863989766\\
6   -0.119500047731206\\
7   -0.1794999297787\\
8   -0.118499920917993\\
9   -0.206499892438547\\
10  -0.1514999680987\\
11  -0.0105000375051933\\
12  0.0484998970746079\\
13  0.2054999375486\\
14  0.297499996486305\\
15  0.340500089571283\\
16  0.477500053171494\\
17  0.520500116898769\\
18  0.527499974522247\\
19  0.601499983679697\\
20  0.616499933860055\\
};
\end{axis} 

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.521in,
height=3.566in,
at={(0.758in,0.481in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
xtick={\empty},
xlabel={Time (seconds)},
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
ytick={\empty},
ylabel={Amplitude},
axis line style={draw=none},
ticks=none,
title style={font=\bfseries},
title={Simulated Response Comparison},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

I hope someone can help me figure out what's causing this error.

**Update**:

- As per Marijn's recommendation I have removed `forget plot` and I ran the code again on the original data and obtained the following output:
  [image]

However, the simulated output on MATLAB looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Maybe you can add a few rows of data in the correct format at the position where you put your `%A bunch of I/O data%` comment, and also add the required document structure around the plots, i.e., documentclass, usepackages, begin/end document. By doing this you can compile the code yourself and verify that it produces the same error, and this also provides a better starting point for people that want to try finding a solution.

Comment: I have edited the question based on your suggestion and made the code compileable by just copy pasting it. I included first 20 datapoints @Marijn

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I get a different error now though, `Runaway argument?
20 0.6165` because you didn't put \\ on the last data line. When adding that I indeed get the original error.

Comment: Oh I fixed that again, but when I run it now I obtain the error which I originally received regarding a missing } @Marijn Thank you for pointing this.

Comment: Could you also share a screenshot from Matlab on how it is supposed to look? I got a plot without errors by removing `forget plot` but I'm not sure if the output is correct.

Comment: Thank you once more for helping me @Marijn I have edited the question to display results after I attempted once more to run the code this time as per your suggestion I removed ```forget plot``` and this time I obtained a graph, it seems that there is some plot below that's overwriting the original matlab plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from automatic conversion scripts like `matlab2tikz`, `svg2tikz`, `dot2tex` and others is often more complex than needed, causing deficiencies in the output or even errors. This is not necessarily to be blamed on these scripts themselves, as automatic conversion is a very difficult problem - however often it is a better solution to write the `pgfplots` code yourself from scratch or to export the plots from your original program as PDF and include them as-is.

However, for the current plot some simplifications are possible that seem to approach the original output.

First I removed the final plot that was just adding the title, and added a `title` option in the first axis.

Second I removed the separate `\begin{axis} \end{axis}` environments for the two plots and put them together in a single `axis` environment with two `\addplot table` statements in the body of the environment, which is the normal procedure when you want to plot multiple lines. This also removes the need for `forget plot` which was causing the error.

Third I added the axis titles and modified the second plot attributes to be red and dashed, and added the two `\addlegendentry` statements in the right order. Just for the MWE I also moved the legend to the bottom right (`south east`) position not to overlap with the plot lines.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.448in,
height=3.461in,
at={(0.831in,0.481in)},
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={white!40!black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{white!40!black}},
every x tick/.append style={white!40!black},
xmin=1,
xmax=25,%411,
every outer y axis line/.append style={white!40!black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{white!40!black}},
every y tick/.append style={white!40!black},
ymin=-1,
ymax=0.8,
ylabel style={font=\color{white!40!black}},
ylabel={\textcolor{black}{Amplitude} (y1)},
xlabel={Time (seconds)},
title={Simulated Response Comparison},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black},
legend pos=south east,
]
\addplot [color=white!60!black]%, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   0.2845\\
2   0.2365\\
3   0.0805\\
4   -0.0615\\
5   -0.0115\\
6   -0.1195\\
7   -0.1795\\
8   -0.1185\\
9   -0.2065\\
10  -0.1515\\
11  -0.0105\\
12  0.0485\\
13  0.2055\\
14  0.2975\\
15  0.3405\\
16  0.4775\\
17  0.5205\\
18  0.5275\\
19  0.6015\\
20  0.6165\\
};
\addplot [color=red,dashed]%, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{
1   0.284500056219376\\
2   0.23650004412451\\
3   0.0805000155159026\\
4   -0.0615000481945472\\
5   -0.0115000863989766\\
6   -0.119500047731206\\
7   -0.1794999297787\\
8   -0.118499920917993\\
9   -0.206499892438547\\
10  -0.1514999680987\\
11  -0.0105000375051933\\
12  0.0484998970746079\\
13  0.2054999375486\\
14  0.297499996486305\\
15  0.340500089571283\\
16  0.477500053171494\\
17  0.520500116898769\\
18  0.527499974522247\\
19  0.601499983679697\\
20  0.616499933860055\\
};
\addlegendentry{val\_dat (y1)}
\addlegendentry{m1: 88.97\%}
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]